# How can I get a logic output from a temperature sensor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, sensor, temperature, lm35

1. I need a logic high or logic low output from an LM35. If the temperature exceeds the preset temperature threshold, the logic level output will be generated from the LM35.  The preset temperature threshold can be 80 °C.
2. Is there a temperature sensor that does this without the need for an extra circuit?

Note, I need low power consumption. The temperature sensor or external circuit for the LM35 shouldn't exceed 1mA.

Comment: You're asking for digital temperature while the LM35 is an analog sensor. You should take a step back and "let go" of the LM35 because it cannot do what you want. Explain what behavior you need  and don't ask for a product (sensor) that can do this as that would make this a shopping question so it gets closed. I suggest you look at temperature sensors on Digikey and Mouser to see if what you want exists.

Answer (score 4):

There are temperature sensors with built-in reference and comparator, however you may not like the price and/or the package. Generally not-so-popular older parts subject to possible availability issues, since more modern parts will be configured via SMBUS or I2C or SPI.

You could also consider using an NTC thermistor (for example, 100K at 25°C). They are available as SMT parts or bead type.

A simple bridge circuit and a comparator would suffice for a fixed setpoint, no reference necessary. For example a 100K thermistor might have resistance at 70°C of 13.96K +/-1% (which represents an accuracy of < 0.25°C). It's not too difficult to keep the current consumption < 1mA even with a super-cheap [LM393](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393b.pdf?ts=1622635880130&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM393B) comparator.

---

Edit: For example:

[image]

Pick R5 to be the value of the thermistor at the desired temperature trip point (from the thermistor datasheet). Vout is high for temperature < trip point, and is pulled low for temperature > trip point.

Comment: hello thanks for comment.Can you easily share circuit scheme?for 100k ntc?

Answer (score 3):

You can't reliably get a logic high or low from the LM35 alone, as it only produces an analog value.

However, you can use a comparator to compare the voltage coming from the LM35 against some preset value corresponding to the 80 °C threshold you need. There are even chips like the [TLV3012](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv3012.pdf) with an exposed internal voltage reference, so you don't need to provide your own or rely on the voltage accuracy of the supply rails. Depending on your application, you may also want to add some hysteresis.

Ad 2): If you don't need too much accuracy (±3~10 °C), perhaps you could use a simple [bimetallic thermostat switch](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/657/ourproducts_5003_datasheet-1315949.pdf). 80 °C is likely well within their range.

Bonus: these don't require any additional power, apart from pull-up/down resistors or suchlike to interface your micro.

Comment: Or a "Window Comparator" perhaps.

Comment: @rdtsc Why a window comparator? They've only asked about activating an output above some threshold value, not activating it within a window of values. But sure, it could be used if one sets the higher threshold of the window higher than all (most?) practical values output by the LM35. :/  That seems a bit less obvious. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was thinking of an acceptable operating range, not an arbitrarily high ceiling.

Comment: I see, that would make sense.